# I need to run script if table doesn't exist using sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have to run a specific code using sqlplus but only if a certain table does not exist in a database. For example: codeA.sql runs codeB.sql but only when tableB exists.

I tried using "@codeB" inside an IF clause within codeA.sql, also tried using execute immediate.

```sql
        BEGIN

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM user_tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE   
        'tableB';
        IF cnt = 0 THEN 
        @create_tableB_script.sql 
        END IF;

        END;
```

I expect that codeA runs codeB which is in a file named codeB.sql when a condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

> Table names in Oracle are stored as uppercase, e.g. case insensitive
>   unless they're quoted such as `"tAbLeB"`.

So, use

`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM user_tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TABLEB';`

**or**

`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM user_tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE upper('tableB');`

**or**

`SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM user_tables WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(TABLE_NAME,'tableB','i');`
[ --> `'i'` stands for insensitive search ]

to be able to see the related table. Btw, like operators might be replaced by equality(`=`) operator. But, `... WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tableB'` does not return a count value more than zero.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case. The exact part that is not working is this:
```sql

        IF cnt = 0 THEN 
        @create_tableB_script.sql 
        END IF;

Comment: welcome @DjBesk , I understand that you a value returns greater than zero to the variable `cnt`, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it returns 0, the problem is with running the 
```

        @create_tableB_script.sql

Comment: @DjBesk do you still get 0, when you query by `WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEB';` ?